# How to create a swipe down gesture in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a swipe down gesture that runs a function when detected.

```
.gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.height > 0 && abs(value.translation.height) > abs(value.translation.width) {
                        addTask()
                    }
                }
        )
```

this is the closest i got but with this implementation it makes the swipeActions attatched to the forEach slow and laggy.
is there a better way ?

Full code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import UserNotifications

// Custom Yellow
let yellowCustom = Color(red: 1, green: 0.811, blue: 0, opacity: 1.0)

struct ContentView: View {
//SwiftData
@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Task.complete), SortDescriptor(\Task.date, order: .reverse)]) var task: [Task]
@State private var path = [Task]()
let firstLaunchKey = "hasLaunchedBefore"


var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        List {
            ForEach(task) { task in
                TasksView(task: task)
                    .strikethrough(task.complete)
                    .foregroundColor(task.complete ? .gray : .primary)
                
                //Done Gesture
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                        if task.complete {
                            Button("Not Done") {
                                notDone(task: task)
                            }
                            .tint(.yellow)
                        } else {
                            Button("Done") {
                                done(task: task)
                            }
                            .tint(.green)
                        }
                    }
            }
            //Delete Gesture
            .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
        }
        .animation(.default, value: task)
        
        //addTask Gesture
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.height > 0 && abs(value.translation.height) > abs(value.translation.width) {
                        addTask()
                    }
                }
        )
        .navigationTitle("Tasks")
    }
    .onAppear {
        requestNotificationPermission()
        checkFirstLaunch()
    }
}

// addTask
func addTask() {
    let task = Task()
    isEditing = true
    modelContext.insert(task)
}

// deleteTask
func deleteTask(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
    for index in indexSet {
        let task = task[index]
        modelContext.delete(task)
    }
}

// swipeDone
func done(task: Task) {
    task.complete = true
}

// swipeNotDone
func notDone(task: Task) {
    task.complete = false
}

//Notifications permission
func requestNotificationPermission() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("Permission granted")
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

//Checks if user launched the app before
func checkFirstLaunch() {
    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: firstLaunchKey) {
        // First launch, initialize tasks
        initializeTasksWithCustom()

        // Set the flag to true so this doesn't run again
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: firstLaunchKey)
    }
}


//Guide tasks
func initializeTasksWithCustom() {
    let customTask1 = Task()
    customTask1.title = "swipe right to mark us uncompleted"
    customTask1.complete = true

    let customTask2 = Task()
    customTask2.title = "Swipe right to complete"

    let customTask3 = Task()
    customTask3.title = "Swipe left to delete"

    modelContext.insert(customTask1)
    modelContext.insert(customTask2)
    modelContext.insert(customTask3)

    try? modelContext.save()
}
}

//Sort Boolean
extension Bool: Comparable {
public static func <(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    // the only true inequality is false < true
    !lhs && rhs
}
}
```

Edit: minimal reproducible example

```
//
//  mimal_reproducible_example.swift
//  Yupp(List)
//
//  Created by Hamza Osama on 1/31/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct mimal_reproducible_example: View {

private struct Tasks: Identifiable {
    var id: String { title }
    var title: String
    var discription: String
    var sub: String
    var date: Date
    var complete: Bool
    var dueDate: Date
}

private var tasks: [Tasks] = [
    Tasks(title: "Swipe right to complete", discription: "", sub: "", date: .now, complete: false, dueDate: .now),
    Tasks(title: "Swipe left to delete", discription: "", sub: "", date: .now, complete: false, dueDate: .now),
    Tasks(title: "swipe right to mark us uncompleted", discription: "", sub: "", date: .now, complete: true, dueDate: .now)
]

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(tasks) { tasks in
                Text(tasks.title)
                    .strikethrough(tasks.complete)
                    .foregroundColor(tasks.complete ? .gray : .primary)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                        if tasks.complete {
                            Button("Not Done") {
                                print("Not Done")
                            }
                            .tint(.yellow)
                        } else {
                            Button("Done") {
                                print("Done")
                            }
                            .tint(.green)
                        }
                    }
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                        Button("Delete") {
                            print("Delete Task")
                        }
                        .tint(.red)
                    }
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    if value.translation.height > 0 && abs(value.translation.height) > abs(value.translation.width) {
                        print("Add Task")
                    }
                }
        )
        .navigationTitle("Tasks")
    }
}
}

#Preview {
mimal_reproducible_example()
}
```

Edit: Trying solution 1:

```
//
//  mimal_reproducible_example.swift
//  Yupp(List)
//
//  Created by Hamza Osama on 1/31/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct SwipeAction<Content: View>: View {

//MARK: - PROPERTIES
var cornerRadius: CGFloat = .zero
var direction: SwipeDirection = .trailing
@ViewBuilder var content: Content
@ActionBuilder var actions: [Action]

/// View Properties
@Environment(\.colorScheme) private var scheme
let viewID = UUID()
@State private var isEnabled = true
@State private var scrollOffset: CGFloat = .zero

var body: some View {
    
    /// Used to reset the scroll view to its original position     when a swipe action is tapped
    ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                content
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(direction == .leading ? -180 : 0))
                    /// To take the full available space
                    .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    .background(scheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                    .background {
                        if let firstAction = filteredActions.first {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(firstAction.tint)
                                .opacity(scrollOffset == .zero ? 0 : 1)
                        }
                    }
                    .id(viewID)
                    .transition(.identity)
                    .overlay {
                        GeometryReader {
                            let minX = $0.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal)).minX
                            
                            Color.clear
                                .preference(key: OffsetKeySwipe.self, value: minX)
                                .onPreferenceChange(OffsetKeySwipe.self) {
                                    scrollOffset = $0
                                }
                        }
                    }
                
                ActionButtons() {
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        scrollProxy.scrollTo(viewID, anchor: direction == .trailing ? .topLeading : .topTrailing)
                    }
                }
                .opacity(scrollOffset == .zero ? 0 : 1)
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
            .visualEffect { content, geometryProxy in
                content
                    .offset(x: scrollOffset(geometryProxy))
            }
            
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned) // <-- Requires scrollTargetLayout() insiede the ScrollView
        .background {
            if let lastAction = filteredActions.last {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(lastAction.tint)
                    .opacity(scrollOffset == .zero ? 0 : 1)
            }
        }
        .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: cornerRadius))
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(direction == .leading ? 180 : 0))
        
    } //: ScrollView Reader
    .allowsHitTesting(isEnabled)
    .transition(CustomTransition())
}

/// Action Buttons
@ViewBuilder
func ActionButtons(resetPosition: @escaping () -> Void) -> some     
View {
    /// Each button will have a 100 of Width
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.clear)
        .frame(width: CGFloat(filteredActions.count) * 100)
        .overlay(alignment: direction.alignment) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                
                ForEach(filteredActions) { button in
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            isEnabled = false
                            resetPosition()
                            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.25))
                            button.action()
                            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.1))
                            isEnabled = true
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: button.icon)
                            .font(button.iconFont)
                            .foregroundStyle(button.iconTint)
                            .frame(width: 100)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .contentShape(.rect)
                    } //: Button
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    .background(button.tint)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(direction == .leading ? -180 : 0))

                } //: LOOP
                
            } //: HSTACK
        } //: RECTANGLE
}

func scrollOffset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
    let minX = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal)).minX
    return (minX > 0 ? -minX : 0)
}

var filteredActions: [Action] {
    return actions.filter({ $0.isEnabled })
}

}

/// Offset Key
struct OffsetKeySwipe: PreferenceKey {
static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero

static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
    value = nextValue()
}
}


/// Custom Transition
struct CustomTransition: Transition {
func body(content: Content, phase: TransitionPhase) -> some View         
{
    content
        .mask {
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                
                Rectangle()
                    .offset(y: phase == .identity ? .zero : -size.height)
            }
            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
        }
}
}


/// Swipe Direction
enum SwipeDirection {
case leading
case trailing

var alignment: Alignment {
    switch self {
        
    case .leading:
        return .leading
        
    case .trailing:
        return .leading
        
    }
}
}

struct Action: Identifiable {

private(set) var id = UUID()
var tint: Color
var icon: String
var iconFont: Font = .title
var iconTint: Color = .white
var isEnabled: Bool = true
var action: () -> Void

}

@resultBuilder
struct ActionBuilder {

static func buildBlock(_ components: Action...) -> [Action] {
    return components
}

}

struct mimal_reproducible_example: View {

private struct Tasks: Identifiable {
    var id: String { title }
    var title: String
    var discription: String
    var sub: String
    var date: Date
    var complete: Bool
    var dueDate: Date
}

private var tasks: [Tasks] = [
    Tasks(title: "Swipe right to complete", discription: "", sub: "", date: .now, complete: false, dueDate: .now),
    Tasks(title: "Swipe left to delete", discription: "", sub: "", date: .now, complete: false, dueDate: .now),
    Tasks(title: "swipe right to mark us uncompleted", discription: "", sub: "", date: .now, complete: true, dueDate: .now)
]

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                ForEach(tasks) { tasks in
                    SwipeAction {
                        Text(tasks.title)
                            .strikethrough(tasks.complete)
                            .foregroundColor(tasks.complete ? .gray : .primary)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                            .padding(.leading, 20)
                    } actions: {
                        Action(tint: .red, icon: "trash") {
                            print("Delete")
                        }
                        
                        Action(tint: .green, icon: "checkmark") {
                            print("Done / Undone")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .background(.background)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Tasks")
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    print("Value: \(value.translation.height)")
                    if value.translation.height > 0 && abs(value.translation.height) > abs(value.translation.width) {
                        print("Add Task")
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
}

#Preview {
mimal_reproducible_example()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a mimal reproducible example which work in a blank project without SwiftData stuff? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Those swipe actions seem to be buggy even without the gesture for some reason. I still can't figure out why though. I can provide you with some Home made Swipe Actions that I was using in another project which does not require gestures to work:

```
struct SwipeAction<Content: View>: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = .zero
    var direction: SwipeDirection = .trailing
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    @ActionBuilder var actions: [Action]
    
    /// View Properties
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var scheme
    let viewID = UUID()
    @State private var isEnabled = true
    @State private var scrollOffset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        /// Used to reset the scroll view to its original position when a swipe action is tapped
        ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                
                LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                    content
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(direction == .leading ? -180 : 0))
                        /// To take the full available space
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                        .background(scheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                        .background {
                            if let firstAction = filteredActions.first {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(firstAction.tint)
                                    .opacity(scrollOffset == .zero ? 0 : 1)
                            }
                        }
                        .id(viewID)
                        .transition(.identity)
                        .overlay {
                            GeometryReader {
                                let minX = $0.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal)).minX
                                
                                Color.clear
                                    .preference(key: OffsetKeySwipe.self, value: minX)
                                    .onPreferenceChange(OffsetKeySwipe.self) {
                                        scrollOffset = $0
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    
                    ActionButtons() {
                        withAnimation(.snappy) {
                            scrollProxy.scrollTo(viewID, anchor: direction == .trailing ? .topLeading : .topTrailing)
                        }
                    }
                    .opacity(scrollOffset == .zero ? 0 : 1)
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
                .visualEffect { content, geometryProxy in
                    content
                        .offset(x: scrollOffset(geometryProxy))
                }
                
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned) // <-- Requires scrollTargetLayout() insiede the ScrollView
            .background {
                if let lastAction = filteredActions.last {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(lastAction.tint)
                        .opacity(scrollOffset == .zero ? 0 : 1)
                }
            }
            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: cornerRadius))
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(direction == .leading ? 180 : 0))
            
        } //: ScrollView Reader
        .allowsHitTesting(isEnabled)
        .transition(CustomTransition())
    }
    
    /// Action Buttons
    @ViewBuilder
    func ActionButtons(resetPosition: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        /// Each button will have a 100 of Width
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.clear)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(filteredActions.count) * 100)
            .overlay(alignment: direction.alignment) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    
                    ForEach(filteredActions) { button in
                        Button {
                            Task {
                                isEnabled = false
                                resetPosition()
                                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.25))
                                button.action()
                                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.1))
                                isEnabled = true
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: button.icon)
                                .font(button.iconFont)
                                .foregroundStyle(button.iconTint)
                                .frame(width: 100)
                                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .contentShape(.rect)
                        } //: Button
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        .background(button.tint)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(direction == .leading ? -180 : 0))

                    } //: LOOP
                    
                } //: HSTACK
            } //: RECTANGLE
    }
    
    func scrollOffset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minX = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal)).minX
        return (minX > 0 ? -minX : 0)
    }
    
    var filteredActions: [Action] {
        return actions.filter({ $0.isEnabled })
    }
    
}




/// Offset Key
struct OffsetKeySwipe: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}


/// Custom Transition
struct CustomTransition: Transition {
    func body(content: Content, phase: TransitionPhase) -> some View {
        content
            .mask {
                GeometryReader {
                    let size = $0.size
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .offset(y: phase == .identity ? .zero : -size.height)
                }
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
            }
    }
}


/// Swipe Direction
enum SwipeDirection {
    case leading
    case trailing
    
    var alignment: Alignment {
        switch self {
            
        case .leading:
            return .leading
            
        case .trailing:
            return .leading
            
        }
    }
}

struct Action: Identifiable {
    
    private(set) var id = UUID()
    var tint: Color
    var icon: String
    var iconFont: Font = .title
    var iconTint: Color = .white
    var isEnabled: Bool = true
    var action: () -> Void
    
}

@resultBuilder
struct ActionBuilder {
    
    static func buildBlock(_ components: Action...) -> [Action] {
        return components
    }
    
}
```

You just need to copy and paste this and use it like this:

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                ForEach(tasks) { tasks in
                    SwipeAction {
                        Text(tasks.title)
                            .strikethrough(tasks.complete)
                            .foregroundColor(tasks.complete ? .gray : .primary)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                            .padding(.leading, 20)
                    } actions: {
                        Action(tint: .red, icon: "trash") {
                            print("Delete")
                        }
                        
                        Action(tint: .green, icon: "checkmark") {
                            print("Done / Undone")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .background(.background)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Tasks")
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    print("Value: \(value.translation.height)")
                    if value.translation.height > 0 && abs(value.translation.height) > abs(value.translation.width) {
                        print("Add Task")
                    }
                }
        )
```

As for why the gesture does not work most of time I'm still wondering. But at least now you have working swipeActions.
Let me know if you find a way to make gestures work in this scenario, and let me know your thoughts about this solution.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting this code but I got these errors.

Cannot find 'SwipeAction' in scope
Cannot find 'Action' in scope
Cannot find 'Action' in scope

I think for the first error I just have to change SwipeAction to .swipeActions.
but what about the 2 other errors?

Comment: SwipeAction and Action are defined in the first snippet of code.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that. I added it but I got the error:

Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'BackingData' that does not accept a closure

in the Task

ForEach {
    Button {
        Task {

Comment: Try just pasting the second snippet and see if it work before. It should just work out of the box.

Comment: OK, I added the first code snippet and then pasted the second code snippet in my mimal_reproducible_example body but I still get the above error.

Comment: Can you update the code of the question as well? So I can see what you have done.

Comment: Ok i added the updated code to the questions.

Comment: I swear that I just copied and pasted your code with my custom SwipeAction and it works, I can show you if you want. What is your minimum deployment target? Because this only works starting from iOS 17. But even lowering my minimum target to iOS 16 I don't see the kind of errors you are seeing. They should be related to other things in your code.

Comment: I tried adding them to a new project and it worked I don't know why it didn't work on the other project.

Thanks, i will use this method for now but I still wish that the native swipeActions worked better.

Comment: If my solution was useful to you, can you at least upvote my answer please?

Comment: Of course but I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. so I can't sorry.

But thanks a lot you were really helpful 